# Is it guaranteed anywhere in docs that hashes with same keys will also have same order?

Tags: perl, hash

There's not much guarantees about order of hash keys in Perl. Is there any mention in docs that I can't find that would say that as long as two hashes use exactly same keys, they will go in exactly same order?

Short test seems to confirm that. Even if I generate some additional keys for internal key table between assigning to two different hashes, their keys are returned in same order:

```
my %aaa;
my %bbb;
my %ccc;
my %ddd;

@aaa{qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l)}=();
# Let's see if generating more keys for internal table matters
@ccc{qw(m n o p q r s t u v w x)}=();
@bbb{qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l)}=();
# Just to test if different insertion order matters
@ddd{qw(l k c d e f g h i j a)}=(); $ddd{b} = ();

print keys %aaa, "\n";
print keys %bbb, "\n";
print keys %ddd, "\n";
```

However I wouldn't rely on udocumented behavior and only fact that can be easily found in docs is that `keys`, `values` and `each` all will use same order as long as hash is not modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since at least 5.18, following is explicitly mentioned in [perldoc perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks):

> `keys`, `values`, and `each` return items in a per-hash randomized order.
>   Modifying a hash by insertion will change the iteration order of that
>   hash.

---

> Perl has never guaranteed any ordering of the hash keys, and the
>   ordering has already changed several times during the lifetime of Perl
>   5. Also, the ordering of hash keys has always been, and continues to be, affected by the insertion order and the history of changes made to
>   the hash over its lifetime.

Therefore two hashes with same set of keys are explicitly NOT guaranteed to be iterated in same order.

Answer (score 13):

From perlsec:

> **Perl has never guaranteed any ordering of the hash keys**, and the
>   ordering has already changed several times during the lifetime of Perl
>   5. Also, the ordering of hash keys has always been, and continues to be, affected by the insertion order.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html

Comment: Yes, I understand that order itself is not guaranteed, but still it says nothing about if it will be same pseudo-random sequences in different hashes. I've added 3rd hash, with different insertion order: `@ddd{qw(l k c d e f g h i j a)}=(); $ddd{b} = ();` It still shows same order on `print`.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, Disco is pointing out that *no order is guaranteed*, and that does indeed answer your question.  You asked whether a particular kind of order (identical order between two hashes with same keys) was guaranteed, and the answer is no.  It may work for you now, but you can't rely on it working.

Comment: @dan1111, no this single phrase doesn't mean that "no order is guaranteed" because there's another passage in `perldoc -f keys`:  "but it is guaranteed to be the same order as either the values or each function produces." See, we have at least one guarantee and I'm looking if there's another that I need.

Comment: That is about the ordering of keys on the same hash, not about the ordering of keys on different hashes.  There exist no guarantees about the ordering of keys on different hashes.

Answer (score 7):

A longer test disproves.

So, different hashes with the same set of keys *won't* always have the same order.  For me the program below demonstrates that two hashes with keys `qw(a b c d e f)` can differ in ordering:

```
v5.16.0
%h1: ecabdf
%h2: eadcbf
```

Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

# http://stackoverflow.com/q/12724071/132382

use constant KEYS => qw(a b c d e f);

my %h1 = map { $_ => undef } KEYS;
my %h2 = map { $_ => undef } KEYS;

delete @h2{'b', 'd', 'f'};
@h2{'x', 'y', 'z'} = ();
@h2{'b', 'd', 'f'} = ();
delete @h2{'x', 'y', 'z'};

say $^V;
say '%h1: ', keys(%h1);
say '%h2: ', keys(%h2);
```

### Update

Here's a simpler demonstration that insertion order alone matters:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -E \
> '@keys = ('a'..'z'); @h1{@keys} = @h2{shuffle @keys} = ();
> say keys(%$_) for (\%h1, \%h2)'
wraxdjyukhgftienvmslcpqbzo
warxdjyukhgftienmvslpcqbzo
#^^             ^^  ^^
#||             ||  ||
```

Comment: This key reordering holds for me all the way back to 5.8.8

Comment: Well, that's what I kind of expected from beginning. And, additionally, it is hard to prove something does **not** exists in docs, but a practical demonstration is surely the best argument against this assumption.

Answer (score 5):

It is specifically guaranteed that this is undependable.

See the [Algorithmic Complexity Attacks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks) section of `perlsec` in full. Despite its regrettable incoherency, it states that

- in 5.8.1, the order is guaranteed to be random every time.
- in 5.8.2 and later, the order will be the same unless Perl detects pathological behavior (specifically, a series of keys that would all hash to a small number of buckets, causing the hash performance to suffer). In those cases, "the function is perturbed by a pseudorandom seed".

The documentation does *not* guarantee that the ordering will always be the same; in fact, it specifically states that it will *not* be predictable in a pathological case. Should the hashing function be changed in a future release, it's possible that data which previously did not generate degenerate hashing would now do so, and then would be subject to the random perturbation.

So the takeaway is that if you're not using 5.8.1, *maybe* you'll get the same order, and *maybe* it won't change when you update your Perl, but it might. If you are using 5.8.1, then a random order is *guaranteed*.

If you want a dependable order, use one of the CPAN classes that provides a hash that has a guaranteed key order - [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aIndexed), [Tie::IxHash](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aIxHash) - or just sort your keys. If you have a hash that has less than a few thousand keys, you probably won't notice an appreciable difference. If it has more than that, maybe you should consider a heavier-weight solution such as a database anyway.

Edit: and just to make it more interesting, [keys will be randomly ordered as of 5.18](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1005122).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a counter-example that is shorter than [@pilcrow's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730135/100754) (apparently I missed his answer when I first looked at this question):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @hashes = (
    { map { $_ => rand } 'a' .. 'z' },
    { map { $_ => rand } 'a' .. 'd', 'f' .. 'z' }
);

delete $hashes[0]{e};

print "@{[ keys %$_ ]}\n" for @hashes;
```

Output:

```
C:\temp> t
w r a x d j y u k h g f t i n v m s l c p q b z o
w r a x d j y u k h g f t i n v m s l c p b q z o
```

Answer (score 3):

[perldoc -f keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) has some info on the ordering:

> The keys of a hash are returned in an apparently random order. The actual random order is subject to change in future versions of Perl, but it is guaranteed to be the same order as either the values or each function produces (given that the hash has not been modified). **Since Perl 5.8.1 the ordering can be different even between different runs of Perl for security reasons** (see Algorithmic Complexity Attacks in perlsec).

So the only guarantee is that no ordering is guaranteed.

Comment: That is not relevant. I compare order of different hashes, but in same run.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, It's 100% relevant. You have two identical pieces of code, and the quoted paragraphs says that can lead to different orderings, so you can different orderings.

Comment: @ikegami, As I've already mentioned in first comment, I don't care about "different runs of Perl" - I'm interested in SAME run. Therefore it is absolutely not relevant. However I've recently reviewed perlsec mentioned in quote and found much more relevant quote that I've just posted as self-answer.

Comment: I didn't say anything about different runs!?!?